# Definition of $x\left<Y\right>$ notation in probability theory

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I am working on the basics of probability theory in Koller's [Probabilistic Graphical Models - Principles and Techniques](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/probabilistic-graphical-models). Unfortunately I am having trouble understanding a formal definition (possibly because English is not my native language).

From page 21 (Probability Theory - What is a random variable):

> For $X \subseteq Y$ we use $x\left<Y\right>$ [for $x \in X$] to refer to the assignment within $x$ to the variables in $Y$.

$X$ is a set of random variables. What is meant by "assignment within $x$"?

**Update:** A little more context:

> $X$ is used to denote a set of random variables, while $x$ denotes assignment of values to the variables in these sets.

Then the definiton above, and straight after that:

> For two assignments $x$ (to $X$) and $y$ (to $Y$), we say $x\sim y$ if $x\left<X\cap Y\right> = y\left<X\cap Y\right>$.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could use tex. That makes it so much more readable.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are random variables? What does $X \subseteq Y$ mean?

Comment: @Pedro Milet That was clearly mistake number one on my end! $X,Y$ are indeed sets of random variables. I have updated my question with a little more context to avoid further mistakes like this one.

Comment: No idea. Never seen this notation.